403 Error while creating a spreadsheet using a GCP Service Account credentials in gspread python despite correct scopes
I'm encountering a 403 error when attempting to create a Google spreadsheet using the gspread library in Python, despite setting what I believe to be the correct authentication scopes for my service account. The error details are:
{
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Insufficient Permission",
      "domain": "global",
      "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
    }
  ],
  "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
  "details": [
    {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
      "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
      "domain": "googleapis.com",
      "metadata": {
        "service": "drive.googleapis.com",
        "method": "google.apps.drive.v3.DriveFiles.Create"
      }
    }
  ]
}

I am using a service account attached to a VM to authenticate the requests. Below is the Python code snippet triggering the error:
from google.auth import default
import gspread
credentials, _ = default(scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"])
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
sheet_name = 'test_service_account'
sh = gc.create(sheet_name)

Here is what I've tried so far:

I've checked for Google Drive-related roles (like roles/drive.file or
roles/drive) in the IAM console but didn't find them listed for the
service account.
I've explicitly set the necessary scope
(https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive) when initializing the default
service account credentials.
I've ensured that the Google Drive API is enabled for my project. I
have another service account with seemingly the same roles, which is
able to create spreadsheets without any issues.

How can I resolve this permission error? Is there a different way to assign the necessary roles to my service account, or is there something else I might be overlooking?

IIRC Google Workspace services (including Drive) aren't covered by Google Cloud IAM and therefore there are no roles like roles/drive.file. You must instead use OAuth scopes. However, the documentation suggests that you must have added a Service Account's email address to a Google Workspace document (including Sheets) before the Python library is able to access it. This makes sense (though I've never seen this done before) because unless you're using Domain-wide Delegation, Service Accounts aren't permitted to access user Workspace data.

As a consequence, you can't create Sheets using the library because Sheets need to exist before you can add sharing credentials to them.
